# Sanitize a value from select, radio, checkbox?

Tags: php, html

Does a select input (or a checkbox or a radio) need to be sanitized and / or escaped, assuming  that the value will be used in a query? And if yes, why? I mean, how that value could be altered by someone?

Comment: There's no real reason not to sanitize all input. If you sanitize some input but not all, it's like closing the door but leaving the window open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should always sanitize all input. Just because you're giving the user a choice from a select, radio, or checkbox, doesn't mean they can't use the web inspector to change the values they can choose from. Also, they can always manufacture their own GET or POST request to send whatever values they want.

Comment: "Sanitizing" a field that's meant to accept a numeric input or a single word/term, for example, is not nearly as effective as simply casting (for integers, for example) or validating (for known values, like an `ON`/`OFF` or `Y`/`N` field). Sanitizing works when *validating* is not particularly straight forward, like a free-text field. It's too broad to say that some sanitizing filter needs to be done in *every* situation, although it is an important step for *many* situations. It's best to be careful and consider each situation on it's own merits.

Comment: Some people consider validating a subset of sanitizing. For instance, I view sanitizing values as ensuring they're ready for the database or to be displayed (no sql injection, no xss, values are appropriate for the columns they're going in). Also, the question was specifically about sanitizing inputs.

Comment: Sanitizing is not validating; validation requires the ability to test a given piece of data against it's *requirements* (and to know the result affirmatively), whereas sanitizing simply modifies that data's content to fit requirements. Saying the two are the same, or validation is a subset of sanitization, too easily misses the point of both. At most, you may *perform* sanitization filtering while validating to model data consistently for validity checks.

Comment: In the specific I'm doing like this: `$id_category = isset($_GET['id_category']) ? filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id_category', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) : '';` Is this a kind of sanitization/validation...?

Comment: @supadema - You're sanitizing that input, which is good. An example of validating would be if the id categories could only be between 1-64, so say 124 being submitted is obviously *invalid*. This is especially useful if the search query is expensive: Return an error or an empty search result, without having to run the query. This is especially important when committing changes like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` queries. Validating is more important than simply forcing the data into a given format.

Answer (score 1):

`<input name="myradio" type="radio" value="2" />`

becomes

`<input name="myradio" type="text" value="some baaad value" />`

So sanitize all input is the **only** option.